Limit distribution of this discrete time Markov chain is standard normal?
Consider a discrete time, uncountable state space Markov chain with one-step transition density
$$
p^{(1)}(z_0,z)=\mathbf 1_{\{z\leq z_0-\theta\lor z\geq z_0+\theta\}}\phi(z)
+\delta(z-z_0)\left(\Phi(z_0+\theta)-\Phi(z_0-\theta)\right),
$$
where $\theta\geq 0$, $z_0\in\Bbb R$ is the initial state, $\mathbf 1_{\{\cdot\}}$ is the indicator function, $\delta(\cdot)$ is the Dirac delta, $\phi(\cdot)$ is the standard normal density, and $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the standard normal distribution.
The $n$-step transition density is
$$
p^{(n)}(z_0,z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty p^{(m)}(z_0,t)p^{(n-m)}(t,z)\,\mathrm dt,
$$
and the limit distribution is
$$
\pi(z)=\lim_{n\to\infty}p^{(n)}(z_0,z).
$$
Conjecture:
$$
\pi(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-z^2/2}
$$
Simulating pseudo-random observations from the limit distribution is straightforward using the MATLAB code below:
burnIn = 1e4; % burn-in chain with burnIn number of observations
N = 1e9; % number of desired samples from limit dist.
theta = 1;

ZS = LimitDist(theta,N,burnIn);

function dist=LimitDist(theta,N,burnIn)
    ZS = 0; % initial state
    Nt = N+burnIn;
    dist = zeros(Nt,1);
    ZC = normrnd(0,1,Nt,1);
    for n = 1:Nt
    if ZC(n)-ZS>=theta
      ZS = ZC(n);
    elseif ZC(n)-ZS<=-theta
      ZS = ZC(n);
    end
    dist(n) = ZS;
    end
    dist = dist((burnIn+1):end);
end

Here is a histogram of the pseudo-random observations generated in MATLAB compared to the standard normal density:

No matter what value of $\theta$ is used in this code, the pseudo-random observations from the limit distribution appear to be standard normal.
Proof approach:
One way to prove the conjecture is by showing that $\pi(z)$ is functionally independent of $\theta$.  Suppose this is true, then one could choose $\theta=0$, from which it is easy to show that $\pi(z)$ is the standard normal density.
Is $\pi(z)$ functionally independent of $\theta$?
Edit:
As pointed out by @Iosif, what I'm interested in is the limit distribution. Here is a simulation of $p^{(n)}(z_0,z)$ for various $n$, $z_0=0$, and $\theta=1$. As $n$ becomes large, $p^{(n)}(0,z)$ converges to what appears t0 be a standard normal and this happens no matter what the value of $\theta$ is:


You should be more careful with the formulation. The state space of your Markov chain is not just "uncountable"; it is the real line $\mathbb R$. The transition probabilities have a singular component, and therefore it is better to avoid talking about their densities (although that's apparently OK in physical parlance). Let me rewrite your  definition of the transition probabilities. If $\mu$ denotes the standard normal distribution with the density $\varphi$, then the transition probability $\pi_z$ from a point $z\in\mathbb R$ is
$$
\pi_z = \mu(I_z)\delta_z + \mu|_{I_z^c} \;,
$$
where $I_z$ denotes the interval $[z-\theta,z+\theta]$, and $I_z^c=\mathbb R\setminus I_z$ denotes its complement. Let $P$ denote the associated Markov transition operator. Then an immediate calculation shows that $\mu P=\mu$ (i.e., the measure $\mu$ is $P$-stationary). Indeed, the density of $\mu P$ at a point $z\in\mathbb R$ is
$$
\mu(I_z)\varphi(z) + \int\limits_{|z'-z|>\theta} \varphi(z)\,dz' 
= \mu(I_z)\varphi(z) + (1-\mu(I_z))\varphi(z) = \varphi(z) \;.
$$
Of course, the fact that $\mu$ is normal plays no role in this argument, and the claim is actually true for any absolutely continuous distribution on $\mathbb R$.
EDIT. If one is interested in the limit behaviour of the one-dimensional distributions $\pi_z^n$ of the chain with the above transition probabilities $\pi_z$, then the key observation is that these transition probabilities satisfiy Doeblin's condition (D) in Doob's formulation (see Doob's Stochastic processes, Section V.5) with respect to the measure $\mu$. Namely, there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $\pi_z(A)<1-\varepsilon$ for any $A\subset\mathbb R$ with $\mu(A)<\varepsilon$ and any $z\in\mathbb R$. Indeed, by the definition of the transition probabilities,
$$
\pi_z(A) \le \mu(I_z) + \mu(A)
$$
for any $A\subset \mathbb R$. Clearly, $\sup_z\mu(I_z)<1$, and therefore one can choose $\varepsilon$ in such a way that $\mu(I_z)<1-2\varepsilon$ for any $z\in\mathbb R$. If $\mu(A)<\varepsilon$, then by the above inequality $\pi_z(A)< 1-\varepsilon$.
Now, the fact that $\mu$ is the unique stationary distribution of the chain, and that $\|\pi_z^n - \mu\|\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ for any initial point $z\in\mathbb R$ follows from the general theory explained in Section V.5 of Doob's book (see Theorem 5.7 and the particular cases (e), (f)).

@Iosif Pinelis Then he should have first proved the existence of this limit. As you are certainly aware of, it is not granted. However, to prove that the exhibited stationary measure is unique, and that the one-dimensional distributions converge to it in total variation is not a big deal either.

@IosifPinelis Yes, I am asking about the limit distribution. We have a Markov chain ${Z_1,Z_2,\dots}$ where the density of $Z_1$ is $p^{(1)}$ and the density of $Z_n$ is $p^{(n)}$.  I am interested in the density of $\lim_{n\to\infty}Z_n$, which I call $\pi$.  My conjecture is that $\pi$ is standard normal.

@Aaron Hendrickson $\lim Z_n$ doesn't exist! However, the distributions of $Z_n$ do converge in total variation. I will add the details if this is what you are interested in.

@RW Yes, please add those details.
